# Finding the CDF of a Sum of I.I.D Continuous Random Variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Let X$_1$ and X$_2$ be identically independent distributions(i.i.d) random variables with

$$\Bbb P(X_i \le x) = 1-x^{-1/2}, \quad x \ge 1 \ \text{and} \ i = 1,2 $$

Find $\Bbb P(X_1 + X_2 \le x)$.

I tried to finding the convolution of $f_{X_1}$ and $f_{X_2}$ (the density functions for $X_1$ and $X_2$) and integrating to get the CDF of $X_1$ + $X_2$ which is what I interpreted the question is asking for. When I integrate it, it got really messy and I could not finish the integration. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Wolframalpha gives the answer using hypergeometric functions. I think there is no hope to get simple answer.

Comment: I actually just noticed that the exponent of -1/3 is incorrect. It’s suppose to be -1/2 if that makes a difference. I’ll make the correction now

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_1%5E%7Bx-1%7D+t%5E%7B-3%2F2%7D(x-t)%5E%7B-3%2F2%7Ddt